# How to improve CMake Package Reusability

Tags: c++, cmake, package

My question is focused on CMake C++ projects and separating out code into multiple repositories for re-usability, and somewhat mimicking a naive package management system. For now I would like to ignore any possible package managers like Conan or vcpkg.

Suppose I have a C++ repository `PackageA` that uses CMake and supplies its own find package file `FindPackageA.cmake` so that it can be used in another CMake package. This file may do some checking to see if `PackageA` is already installed locally on the system (like its headers and lib files exist in some known location) and if not it will compile `PackageA` and install it locally (ideally this package would be versioned so it could find version 1, 2, ect. if requested).

I know have another package `PackageB` which wishes to consume `PackageA`. In theory, if both of these projects lived in a version control system like Github, I assume `PackageB` would have a `CMakeLists.txt` file that contains

```
...

# Download PackageA locally so that we get FindPackageA.cmake file
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjectA
  GIT_REPOSITORY    MY_PACKAGE_A_GITHUB_REPO
  GIT_TAG           origin/release/1
)

# Run the FindPackageA.cmake file to get the headers and libs to link and use against.
find_package(PackageA)

...
```

My one problem with this potential solution is that it requires downloading `PackageA` every time to get its find package file. Is there a more maintainable way to separate out multiple CMake projects so that they can be easily resued here? Would it be better to have a single respository/package that just contains all the find package files so that they are separate from their respective packages?